# (Symfony2) The file "filters/assets.xml" does not exist

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I'm fairly new to symfony framework, I started with symfony 2.8 - and thus I'm still learning. I installed a bootstrap with help of [this][1], and when I typed command to create a bundle, error came up. I guess it's something with cssrewrite filter (I googled the error itself and information about cssrewrite). What I am doing wrong?

The error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException] 
The file "filters/assets.xml" does not exist (in: C:\xampp\htdocs\1\vendor\
symfony\assetic-bundle\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config).
```

My config.yml:

```
    imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
        assets:
        bootstrap_js:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
        bootstrap_css:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css
            filters: [cssrewrite]

        bootstrap_glyphicons_ttf:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"
        bootstrap_glyphicons_eot:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"
        bootstrap_glyphicons_svg:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg"
        bootstrap_glyphicons_woff:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"

        jquery:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.js

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its long time ago, but today i had the same issue.
the solution is to set the "assets"-Node under the right node, in your example is the "assets" under "filters", but this must under the root-node from assetic.